# How to play .wmv file in HTML/jsp page in fire fox?

Tags: firefox

Please suggest something apart from below code as this code is not working in FF.

```
 <!--<OBJECT ID="MediaPlayer" WIDTH="192" HEIGHT="190" CLASSID="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-    0080C74C7E95" STANDBY="Loading Windows Media Player components..." TYPE="application/x-oleobject">
    <PARAM NAME="FileName" VALUE="videofilename.wmv">
    <PARAM name="ShowControls" VALUE="true">
    <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="false">
    <PARAM name="ShowDisplay" VALUE="false">
    <PARAM name="autostart" VALUE="false">
    <EMBED TYPE="application/x-`enter code here`mplayer2" SRC="videofilename.wmv"     NAME="MediaPlayer" WIDTH="192" HEIGHT="190" ShowControls="1" ShowStatusBar="0" ShowDisplay="0" autostart="0"> </EMBED>
    </OBJECT>-->
```